# IIS Rewrite Rule how to check requesturl + .php file is exists or not in rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis-7, url-rewriting

i want to check that file with requestedurl + .php is exists or not.

in apache i can do this with RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

so that it can rewrite my request test.com/login to test.com/login.php

i want to do same with iis rewrite rule.

i have tried with following.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php" matchType="IsFile" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="allpages.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

but it doesnt works.

thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

Change `{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php` to `{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` in first rule.

Further there is no need to check if requested URL exists as directory.

To rewrite 'test.com/login' to 'test.com/login.php' only if login.php exits, use:

```
<rule name="Rewrite to PHP">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php" />
</rule>
```

Tested