# How to check a file in a sub-folder for IIS Rewrite?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

The following in web.config for rewrite **works fine**:

```
<rule name="foo" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="foo.dat$"/>
  <conditions>
    <!-- Match brotli requests -->
    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="br" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="_compressed_br/foo.dat" />
</rule>
```

I want to add a condition to make sure the rewriting is done only if the compressed file in the sub-folder exists:

```
<rule name="foo" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="foo.dat$"/>
  <conditions>
    <!-- Match brotli requests -->
    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="br" />
    <!-- Check if the pre-compressed file exists on the disk -->
    <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_compressed_br/foo.dat" matchType="IsFile" negate="false" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="_compressed_br/foo.dat" />
</rule>
```

The rewriting never happens with the condition.  This means the checking always returns false. I have also tried the following for the condition to no avail:

```
<add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}_compressed_br/foo.dat" matchType="IsFile" negate="false" />
<add input="/_compressed_br/foo.dat" matchType="IsFile" negate="false" />
<add input="_compressed_br/foo.dat" matchType="IsFile" negate="false" />
```

Could you anyone offer a tip on this?

Edit (2019-09-27):
Folder structure:

[image]

Web app foo's directory is ...\dist.
The URL to open the web application is:
http://localhost/foo/

Edit (2019-09-30):
[image]

Edit (2019-10-01):

The accepted answer works like a charm for the above problem.

I have a new challenge.
If I put the web file in the following directory:
C:\mywebsite\home\dist\web.config

The website is bound to port 8086. I can browse the following web page:
https://localhost:8086/home/dist/

To make the rewrite work, I would have to use the following:

```
 <add input="{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}home\dist\_compressed_br\foo.dat" matchType="IsFile" negate="false" />
```

Since I may put the contents under folder dist with the corresponding web.config in any directory, I am wondering if there is a parameter that can replace "{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}home\dist" so that I can use the same web.config no matter where I put them.

Comment: you could try to match like: <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/_compressed_br/foo.dat" /> this server variable match The path-absolute part of the URI.example if you enter http://www.sample.com/s2 it will return /s2 .

Comment: @JanviPanchal Thank you for trying to help.  I did exactly as you wrote, but it did not work. I also tried without the first forward slash: <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="_compressed_br/foo.dat" />, it failed too.  The test url is: "localhost/mywebapp/" Actually, I could download foo.dat with   "localhost/mywebapp/_compressed_br/foo.dat", so your suggestion is supposed to work.  I red somewhere the URL needs to be translated to a file path somehow.

Comment: could you share your folder structure and test url? and also try to use failed request tracing to get more detail why your rule is not working[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Comment: you could refer this links on how to check file is exist or not by using url rewrite. [link1](https://forums.iis.net/t/1162295.aspx),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595782/iis-rewrite-rule-how-to-check-requesturl-php-file-is-exists-or-not-in-rule),[link3](https://superuser.com/questions/975054/try-to-rewrite-to-a-different-url-if-it-would-result-in-404)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I added the information per your request. I enabled Failed Request tracing, but have not seen anything in the log. I suspect it is not considered as a failed request.

Comment: could you share failed request tracing section snapshot?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I added the screenshot per your request. Thank you for your persistent help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}` to locate your Web app `foo`'s root folder.

Setting a response header `Content-Encoding: br` may also be required to prevent unexpected behaviors such as a file download dialog for `foo.dat` rather than displaying its decoded response.

So here's the rule you need:

```xml
<rule name="foo" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^foo\.dat$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="br" />
        <!-- {APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH} equals to {DOCUMENT_ROOT} + "dist\" in your setup -->
        <add input="{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}_compressed_br\foo.dat" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="_compressed_br/foo.dat" />
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="RESPONSE_Content-Encoding" value="br" />
    </serverVariables>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thank you again for the help.  I am wondering if you could lend your capable hand again if you do not mind.  Since it is hard to describe it in the comment here, I appended the new challenge to the original question.  Could you take a look at it?  If you think it is better to create another question, I will be happy to do that.

Comment: @Hong By addressing [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions) I suggest you to ask a new follow-up question with more details, web site root directory, web application's root directory etc. Besides there might be better solutions like one HTTP module file rather than several `web.config`s.

Comment: Thank you.  Will do tomorrow.  Late night here.

Comment: I posted the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219097/how-to-specify-the-file-path-in-web-config-for-checking-file-existence